# Setting colours to FlexiGrid rows based on a value in a certain column

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

I have a client who would like to have each row in FlexiGrid a different colour based on a value in a specific column. The column is a Status column and the status will either be 'Open' or 'Closed'.

Is this possible? If so, could someone give me some guidelines as to how to go about doing it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have converted the text color inside the column based on the status. And not the row color. Will this suit you?

Comment: I'll have to discuss that with the client, but if he isn't happy with that then he'll just have to settle for it the way it is because I haven't been able to find anything to change row colour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function StyleRows(){
    $("tr").each(function() {
        var st = $(this).find("td").eq(0).text();
        if (st != "0" && st != "1"){ $(this).css("color", "black");}
        else if (st == "1")  { $(this).css("color", "green");}
        else if (st == "0")  { $(this).css("color", "red");}
    });
}
```

Comment: Had to modify it a bit but it works. Who knew coming back to this question almost 3 months later and I would get an answer. Thanks!

Comment: this solution always set the color green to the first row, how can i change it to any other row?

Comment: @Fernando Santiago Change the value in .eq()

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in my comment, here is the code to change the color of the text in the column.. and not the row color..

```
foreach (LeaveModel e in _employeeLeaves)
                {

                    if (e.State.Equals("Approved", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        e.State =
                         String.Format("<font color='green'>{0}</font>", e.State);
                    }
                    else if (e.State.Equals("Pending", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        e.State =
                          String.Format("<font color='red'>{0}</font>", e.State);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Did you implement the above solution or do you have any good one for row coloring.. .let us know.. it will be helpful..

Comment: Unfortunately the above solution would not work for us, so the client decided against the coloring